# Chrome desktop PWA Multiple Instances Opening

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

If I click on the app ICON for my PWA (chrome://apps/) for which I have my PWA installed multiple times, a new instance of the PWA is opened for each click.

Is there something I can add to my PWA so it only opens one instance no matter how many link clicks?

Version 76.0.3809.87

Comment: Are you anchor using target of _blank or _top ?

Comment: Sorry, neither. It's the app ICON for my PWA. I have updated the issue.

Comment: are you using the same host and port always? because i tried my app from `(localhost://myapp)` and `(127.0.0.1:8080//myapp)` and two different instances were installed for my app

Comment: It's the chrome installed PWA. Clicking on the icon in the Chrome apps page. So it should always be the same.

Comment: It's not just my app. Must be a Chrome Defect/Feature. If I install this app (https://threejs.org/editor/), then each time I click on the icon on the apps page it opens a new instance of the app.

Comment: Aha! Didn't get your question correctly, Thought you meant it installs multiple times, Just tried it on my app and same thing happens. Definitely chrome!